# MeshRefinementFunction analogue for ToElementMesh

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

`MeshRefinementFunction` according to the documentation is an option for `DiscretizeRegion`. Is there  an analogue for `ToElementMesh`?

The following code

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]; 
f = Function[{vertices, area}, If[Mean[vertices] > 1, area > 0.1, area > 0.01]]; 
ToElementMesh[Interval[{0, 2}], MeshRefinementFunction -> f]
```

gives the error

> ToElementMesh::mrff: The MeshRefinementFunction Function[{vertices, area}, If[Mean[vertices]>1, area > 0.1, area > 0.01]] is not valid and will be ignored. The function does not return either True or False.

so I have to use an ugly workaround

```
mymesh = DiscretizeRegion[Interval[{0, 2}], MeshRefinementFunction -> f]; 
ToElementMesh[mymesh]
```

Comment: I found a similar question here, unanswered: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1928814

Comment: The error message says it all. Try to apply your function `f` to an actual list of vertex positions `vertices` and a number `area`. Then you will see that the `If` statement does not evaluate because `Mean[vertices]` is a vector and not a number.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I am afraid this is a too smart observation for me.:( How should I fix the function f to work with ToElementMesh?

Comment: That depends on what you try to express by `Mean[vertices] > 1`... Maybe you meant to write `f = Function[{vertices, area}, If[Thread[Mean[vertices] > 1], area > 0.1, area > 0.01]]`?  `>` might thread over vectors in other languages, but it does not in _Mathematica_: Things like `{0,0,0}>1` do not produce `True` or `False`, and thus `If[{0,0,0}>1, [...], [...]]` stays just unevaluated. So no `True` nor `False` either.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I just wanted a fine mesh for 0<x<1 and a rough mesh for x>1.

Comment: In what dimension?

Comment: If you mean by `x` the first coordinate, you migth want to use `f = Function[{vertices, area}, If[0<Mean[vertices][[1]] < 1, area > 0.01,  area > 0.1]]`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher In 1D only. I am trying to build the non-homogenous mesh on a 1D interval. Just checked that using Mean[vertices][[1]] gives the same error.:(

Comment: Oh, you're so right! Hm. I am stumped then. But forunately, user21 is around. He is the developer of the FEM tools.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**

The real observation is that `MeshRefinementFunction` does not work for 1D with `ToElementMesh`. Yes, that's unfortunately the case but you can easily use

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
f = Function[{vertices, area}, 
   If[Mean[vertices] > 1, area > 0.1, area > 0.01]];
mr = DiscretizeRegion[Interval[{0, 2}], MeshRefinementFunction -> f];
ToElementMesh[mr]
```

I'll add a note to the documentation until this is implemented.

**Old Answer**

The [Reference Page of ToElementMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToElementMesh.html#1983629671) has examples. Please have a look there.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly that I was reading for the last several hours, together with Element Mesh Generation tutorial. Can not get it to work in 1D case, alas.

Comment: @YashaGindikin, see update.

Comment: BTW, calling `mr` in a context like this `ParallelTable[NDEigenvalues[...,x\in mr]]` does not work. Like the `mr ` is not distributed across the parallel kernels. However, explicit construction like `ParallelTable[NDEigenvalues[...,x\in ToElementMesh[DiscretizeRegion[...]]]]` does work, fortunately.